# How to find cumulative count of committed files in git repository

Tags: git, github

Is there any command or tool which tell cumulative count of committed file in any git repository. 
Example:- I checked in 10 file.
In another commit I modified and pushed 2 files(may or may not be same of previous files). 
I want command which can gives me count 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rev-list --objects --all    | # list everything in history
  awk '{print $1}'              | # just the id, please
  git cat-file --batch-check    | # find out what kind it is
  grep blob                     | # I want only the file content objects
  wc -l                           # specifically, how many different ones there are
```

Comment: That should give 12 instead of 10, as the OP asked. +1

Answer (score 1):

As a first approximation, you can use [`git diff --shortstat`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

For instance, in the git repo itself, the last 4 commits has involved 16 files changes:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>git diff --shortstat @~4
 16 files changed, 509 insertions(+), 438 deletions(-)
```

However, in your case, `git diff --shortstat` would give you 10, not 12.